# I think my ex employer is remotely accessing my laptop

Tags: remote-desktop

I think my ex-employer has been remotely accessing my laptop.

I am sure I caught a glimpse of a sign saying remote access logging out.

There have been a couple of funny mouse moments and I suspect that they have a piece of information they could not have got any other way?

- Can I get a log of remote access times?
- I think they MAY have used `TeamViewer` which appears to have been uninstalled now and not by me?
- Where do I find what exactly was tampered with?

Comment: Check the Windows event log (application and system) for (de)installations.

Comment: If in doubt, start over from scratch - by wiping the hard drive clean, and reinstalling the OS from a verified ISO.

Comment: Please start by confirming what operating system and version you have on your laptop. (TeamViewer [is available for Mac](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/mac-os/) and we shouldn't just _assume_ it's Windows 10). Also: did your former employer manage your computer somehow, with remote tools, while you were employed? Did you log on to a corporate domain from your laptop?

Comment: Shut off Remote Access.  Advanced System Settings, Remote Tab and disable both remote assistance settings and restart.  Look in Programs and Features for VPN apps that you do not want or did not install. These two thing should stop outside access.

Comment: Are you still a part of their domain (if ever)?  Have you looked at users and groups on your own machine that might have remote access?  Are you running a VPN that pipes right into their network?